# Detect input click with dynamic id using JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

In the website is the ability to ask a question and provide answers with images. We have used some website template and now trying to change functionallity. So I'm trying to achieve if image clicked, pop ups upload window (to select picture) and after clicking ok button, it should be shown near the answer (look image below, noted in red).

[image: answers]

There is the ability to add more input fields by clicking the button. It generating HTML like this:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="another-div">
      <div class="image-answer">
         <input type="image" name="answers_images[]" id="test-1" src="image.png">
         <input type="file" name="answers_images[]" id="file-1" style="display: none;">
      </div>
      <label class="text-answer">
         <input type="text" name="answers[]" placeholder="Type here your answer">
      </label>
   </div>
</div>
```

If user clicks the button it will add another row with incremented ids, so it will be `test-2`, `file-2`
after clicking button once again it will add row with incremented ids once again `test-3`, `file-3` and so on.

How can I detect input clicks (via JQuery) if ids are auto incremental? And after it do some changes with JQuery only with clicked ($this) image.

Something like this:

```
$("#file-1...").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();        
    // Some code here, I have working code to achieve what I want
    // But problem, that I have no idea how to detect those clicks with dynamic ids
});

$("#test-1").change(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Give similar elements a `class`. Handle events based on this `class` and with that `$(this)` would be the unique element. Got it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `class` selector instead of `id's` to have a more dynamic approach of what you are trying to achieve. Also with `class` you will be writing less `code` and getting the same results.

You can still use the id's `increment` system to make sure the id's are unique in the `DOM`.

Add `class` to your `input` image and `input` file and and watch a `change` on those classes. You can use `prev()` method you select the previous input of which the change was made on using `$(this)`

```
//Load preview image on each answer
$(document).on('click', '.add_image', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  //add file to input / trigger click
  $(this).next('input').click();
})

//Watch the change on select file
$(document).on('change', '.select_file', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  //get the sibling img src of the change file
  var prevInput = $(this).prev('input')
  //Call read file preview
  previewFile(this, prevInput);
});
```

Pass your `input` and `prev` input image where the change happened to your `previewImage` function so that the `file` can be `previewed` in the image location using `file Reader` API.

```
//Preview img
function previewFile(input , previewSrc) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        //load file into actual preview img
      $(previewSrc).attr('src', e.target.result);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]); // convert to base64 string
  }
}
```

I have added the functionality of adding more `answers` as well and you can upload image and preview images on those new answers as well using `event Delegation` as the `elements` are being append dynamically.

**Complete Working Demo:**

```js
//row with incremented ids
var counter = 2

//Add more
$('#add_more').click(function() {
  //add new answer
  var newRow = `<div class="another-div">
      <div class="image-answer">
         <input type="image" class='add_image' name="answers_images[]" id="test-` + counter + `" src="https://img.icons8.com/dotty/80/000000/upload.png">
         <input type="file" class='select_file' name="answers_images[]" id="file-` + counter + `" style="display: none;">
      </div>
      <label class="text-answer">
         <input type="text" name="answers[]" id="answer-` + counter + `" placeholder="Type here your answer">
      </label>
      <button class="remove_answer"><i class="fas fa-window-close"></i></button>
   </div>`
  //append new answers
  $('.row').append(newRow)
  counter++ //increare counter
})

//remove answer
$(document).on('click', '.remove_answer', function() {
  //remove the answer div
  $(this).parent().remove()
  counter-- //decrease counter
})

//Load preview image on each answer
$(document).on('click', '.add_image', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  //add file to input / trigger click
  $(this).next('input').click();
})

//Watch the change on select file
$(document).on('change', '.select_file', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  //get the sibling img src of the change file
  var prevInput = $(this).prev('input')
  //Call read file preview
  previewFile(this, prevInput);
});

//Preview img
function previewFile(input, previewSrc) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      //load file into actual preview img
      $(previewSrc).attr('src', e.target.result);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]); // convert to base64 string
  }
}
```

```css
.add_image {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="another-div">
    <div class="image-answer">
      <input type="image" class='add_image' name="answers_images[]" id="test-1" src="https://img.icons8.com/dotty/80/000000/upload.png">
      <input type="file" class="select_file" name="answers_images[]" id="file-1" style="display: none;">
    </div>
    <div id="preview_img"></div>
    <label class="text-answer">
         <input type="text" name="answers[]" id="answer-1" placeholder="Type here your answer">
      </label>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<button id="add_more">
  Add New Answer
</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it not just worked, but also I've understood how it's working. Thank you once again!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do event handling on dynamically added content, the trick is using the [.on() method](https://api.jquery.com/on/) with a non-dynamically added parent element, and providing a selector argument. This approach use `classes` instead of `ids`. You cans still have `ids`, but the `this` variable becomes the element selected, so you don't really need them.

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="image-answer dynamically-added" id="answer1"></div>
  <div class="image-answer dynamically-added" id="answer2"></div>
  <div class="image-answer dynamically-added" id="answer3"></div>
</div>

$('.parent').on('click', '.image-answer', function() {});
```

Say if you clicked on the second `.image-answer`, in the event handler function `this` would be the same as `$('#answer2')[0]`. So to make it a jquery object you just have to `$(this)`. And if you want to access a child elemet, just use the [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) method.

```
$(this).find('input[type="file"]').on('change', function previewFile() { ... })
```

Also, `input`s dont' have a default action for `click`, so `e.preventDefault()` isn't necessary.

Comment: This is also explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: Also `input type=image` is a submit button, so will submit if you don't preventDefault https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/image

Comment: I'm sure this has been answered many times on stackoverflow. I know I've answered it a few times myself. But I try to answer it in the context of the question. My goal is to help @Infinity understand what's going on, not just provide copy pasta. Also, you're correct, I was thinking `<input type="text">` when I mention it doesn't need `preventDefault()`. But maybe it'll help someone realize you don't need to call this method for every event handler.

Comment: I do not think this is a duplicate question at all - This is not just only what OP wanted because if you go through the complete question there are a lot of things which should he want considered and he wanted to do that as well which i have covered very briefly in my answer and provided a fully working answer to what OP wanted.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping that's why it a) requires more than 1 vote and b) now makes it a suggestion "does this answer".  :)   It might well have answered the question and frequently it does, perhaps in this case additional details are required.  That's also why I put "this is also explained" (where it's already explained and better) rather than "you should use this answer" - the comment here was providing *additional* information.

Comment: @freedomn-m Indeed I agree on the `event delegation` side of this question but other things are mentioned by OP  as well which OP wanted addressed as well :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation. It was useful to read.